# How does resist from a source that effects a single defense work?

Tags: dnd-4e, damage-resistance

[Grick](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/monster.aspx?id=252) special "Resist 5 against effects that target AC"

Confusion is on the word effect, not target.

Do Hits "Effect" AC? Or do at-wills like sly flourish do full damage?

Comment: Also, welcome to the site, please read our [about].

Comment: @klaumbaz There are many RPGs with many similar concepts - it is sometimes obvious, but you should always state your rpg system here and use the tag for it.

Comment: Unless, of course, you’re explicitly asking a question that could apply to many RPGs and don’t want answers specific to a particular system – then you should use the [tag:system-agnostic] tag.

Answer (score 4):

An [effect](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=302) is:

> The result of a game element’s use. The damage and conditions caused by an attack power are the power’s effects, for instance. Some powers have “Effect” entries, which contain some but not necessarily all of the powers’ effects. In an attack power, the effects of such an entry are not contingent on a hit or a miss.

They use the word to mean two similar but different things. The consequence of a power is an effect, and the "effect line" of a power is *always* part of its effect.